# Converting number to text with Access SQL

Tags: ms-access, csv-import

I have an *.csv file with data. I'm trying to transfer the data to an Access db.

My data look like this

[image]

I'm using an sql `"INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM"`
The construction itself works ok for Access.

The problem comes when I'm trying to convert a value like "99.48%" to a number 99.48
I use `REPLACE([Featured Offer (Buy Box) Percentage],'%','')` and this returns 99.48, but I get a warning - "data type mismatch" if a destination field has a numerical type. When I change field  data type to text then it's ok. But I need numerical, finally like 0.9948

`CDbl(REPLACE([Featured Offer (Buy Box) Percentage],'%',''))` doesn't works - same warning "data type mismatch"

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Sounds like a localization issue, does your Access expect `,` as decimal separator?

Comment: Interesting, Val("99.48%") also gets "data type mismatch". Try Val(Replace("99.48%","%",""))/100.

Comment: However, your CDbl expression should also work. So something else is issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV imports are notorious for localization issues. If the csv has `.` as decimal separator, but your Access/Windows locale expects `,`, it cannot be imported as number.

Your best bet is probably to define an **import specification** where you can specify the decimal separator `.` and field separator `,`.